# Use of integral

Tags: phrases

Which is correct?

Dr. X is integral **to** their mission 
v.s
Dr. X is integral **in** their mission

Comment: _To_ is the more correct word to use, but _in_ technically works as well.

Answer (score 3):

"***Integral to***" is what I would say and expect to hear.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=integral%20to%2C%20integral%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintegral%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintegral%20in%3B%2Cc0) says that's about eight times as common as "integral in" in modern English, and it's the form the several online dictionaries use in their preposition-containing examples.  For example:

> 2. necessary to the completeness of the whole:
>
>    This point is ***integral to*** his plan.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/integral); emphasis added)

> 1 Necessary to make a whole complete; essential or fundamental: [...] systematic training should be ***integral to*** library management

([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/integral); emphasis added)

For what it's worth, however, in your example sentence I think I'd prefer "essential to" over "integral to".

Comment: If you study the Ngram references you will see that virtually all of the uses of "integral in" are in mathematics texts, whereas only about half the uses of "integral to" are used in such contexts.  So "integral in" is virtually never used in the above sense.